# React native can't featch pagination data and getting render error

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I  am trying to get pagination data. first, it will get data from `https://myapi/?page=1` then `https://myapi/?page=2` `https://myapi/?page=3` something like that but don't understand why I am getting this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]')

This error is located at:
in Blog (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Screen)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Background)
in Background (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
in MaybeFreeze (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by MaybeScreen).....
```

here  is my code:

```
const Blog = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  const getBlogs = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://..../blog-api/?page=${count + 1}`
      );
      setCount(count + 1);
      const json = await response.json();
      setData((prev) => [...prev, ...json.results]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getBlogs();
  }, [count]);

 
  return (
    <>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (......my oheres code
```

here is my API response look like:

```
Object {
  "count": 4,
  "next": "https://..../blog-api/?page=4",     
  "previous": "https://backendapi.farhyn.com/blog-api/?page=2", 
  "results": Array [
    Object {
      "author_first_name": "Mickel",
      "author_last_name": "HARTHO",
      "blog_body": "<p>test helo blog</p>",
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Log the response getting from response.json(). I believe you are making mistake over here

```
const json = await response.json();
setData((prev) => [...prev, ...json.results]);
```

The reason for this error is that you are assigning single object to FlatList Data instead of array.

Make sure you have array in in data.
Reason:
setData({})

Comment: you can see my full code. where do I need to edit?

Comment: I think I need to stop the loop when it will reach to the last page.

Comment: I already mentioned the code which is causing the issue please log the response of response.json() i believe its returning object instead of array